Export all data from graphs to an Excel in R Markdown
I'm currently using R Markdown to generate a PDF full of graphs using ggplot. Each chunk of my RMarkdown plots a different graph. However, I need help to export the data processed during the making of each plot. The idea is that after every chunk is processed, the data resulted from that process is exported to, let's say, an Excel sheet. The thing is that I could write some code like:
plot <- ggplot(df) +
   aes(x = x, y = y) +
   geom_col()

processed_data <- plot$data

writexl::write_xlsx(processed_data, "data_from_plot.xlsx", sheet = "plot1")

That would work just fine. The thing is that I have multiple chunks and it would be a lot of work to create this process in all of them. Is there an easier way to export all this data? Thanks!

One possible would be to use a custom knit_print method which besides printing a plot exports the data to an excel sheet. The code below builds on the R Markdown Cookbook and uses openxlsx2 for exporting to XL. The data is added to a sheet with the name of the chunk and hence requires a chunk label. Also note, that for reprex I used a temporary directory to save the Excel file.
---
title: "Export to XL"
output: pdf_document
date: "2024-08-29"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  fig.height = 2
)
```

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

path <- tempdir()
```


```{r}
knit_print.ggplot <- function(x, options, ...) {
  file <- "data_from_plot.xlsx"

  if (file.exists(file.path(path, file))) {
    wb <- openxlsx2::wb_load(file.path(path, file))
    wb <- openxlsx2::wb_add_worksheet(wb, sheet = options$label)
    wb <- openxlsx2::wb_add_data(wb, x = x$data, sheet = options$label)
    openxlsx2::wb_save(wb, file = file.path(path, file))
  } else {
    openxlsx2::write_xlsx(
      setNames(list(x$data), options$label),
      file.path(path, file),
      overwrite = TRUE
    )
  }

  knitr::normal_print(x, ...)
}

registerS3method(
  "knit_print", "ggplot", knit_print.ggplot,
  envir = asNamespace("knitr")
)
```

```{r iris}
ggplot(iris) +
  aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species) +
  geom_point()
```


```{r mtcars}
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = factor(cyl), fill = factor(cyl)) +
  geom_bar()
```

```{r check}
list.files(path, "\\.xlsx$")

readxl::excel_sheets(list.files(path, "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE))
```


